# Creating jar with dependancy information

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I want to create a jar using gradle which have some information about its dependancy So that when someone include it as dependancy, It should download all its dependancy from maven repository. I dont want to include actual jars in my jar like fat jar.

Comment: Then bundle you project using gradle and describe your dependencies in your gradle project file.

Comment: What you're asking for sounds to me exactly like the default behaviour of Gradle. Creating a shaded jar or fat jar requires explicit extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`maven-publish`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin to publish artifacts to maven.
It will generate a minimal POM file with the artifact name and dependencies.
So if someone includes your library into their project it will pull in all the transitive dependencies as required.